# Inconsistent axioms

Tags: set-theory, math-history

As far as I know, no inconsistency is known to descend from the Zermelo-Fraenkel (ZFC) axioms. Question: historically, has a surprising inconsistency been found to descend from any comparably simple, seriously proposed, broadly credited system of axioms?

Another way to ask the question: when it comes to set theory, has the collective intuition of skilled mathematicians ever failed them?

Comment: There seems to be quite a wide gap between your two versions of the question.  It only takes one person to seriously propose a system of mathematics, not mathematicians collectively.

Comment: Early ("naïve") set theory often took as an axiom that the collection of set-theoretic objects satisfying a formula would be a set. [Russell's Paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/) showed that this was not so! Indeed, a contradiction arises in that case from just the Axiom Schema of (unrestricted) Comprehension!

Comment: @EricWofsey In my first version, I should have said, "broadly credited." I will edit.

Comment: @CameronBuie Your observation is well taken. What remains unclear to me is whether early ("naïve") set theory was merely a collection of working proposals or was believed by German mathematics at the time to be a proper, reliable system. Russell is credited with the paradox; but was the mathematical world astonished when Russell presented it, or had mathematicians rather suspected that such paradoxes were likely?

Comment: I don't know of any (besides Frege's set theory); the closest thing I can think of is [Reinhardt cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinhardt_cardinal). I believe there were some people (Reinhardt himself?) who believed that ZFC + "There is a Reinhardt cardinal" would be consistent.  However, my impression that the vast majority of the set-theoretic community was highly skeptical, and indeed $(i)$ it wasn't long before an inconsistency was found and $(ii)$ while substantially harder to establish than Russell's paradox, it still wasn't that complicated.

Comment: (If you're interested, [the original paper](http://math.bu.edu/people/aki/d.pdf) is quite readable; the key point is Theorem 1.12, which only relies on Lemma 1.11; and in fact we only need the cofinality-omega instance, which has a much simpler proof. The whole argument is then less than a page!) Embarrassingly, when I read the relevant part of Reinhardt's thesis I was totally convinced! So I don't know about *mathematicians'* intuition, but *mine* ... I believe the community suspects that (1) ZF+Reinhardt is also inconsistent but (2) the proof will be hard, and the first "deep inconsistency."

Comment: @NoahSchweber One suspects that, at 100k+ rep, you've moved beyond grubbing for points. Nevertheless, I believe that you have just answered my question. Should you get around to posting your comment as an actual *answer,* I would of course upvote.

Comment: @thb Well, as I said, the Reinhardt axiom never actually got much traction and the inconsistency was quickly found and not too hard - that's why I left this as a comment only. I'm happy to add it as an answer if you'd like, but I'm not sure you should be satisfied with it (certainly I would strongly encourage you not to accept it, at least for a while - premature acceptance might deter other, more satisfying answers).